# How to upload image into database in laravel

Tags: mysql, image, laravel

I have add my code for multipleupload:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {

     $image = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

    $filename = time().$image;
    if(Input::hasFile('file')){

        echo 'uploaded <br/>';
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file->move('upload', $filename);
        echo '<img src="upload/' . $filename .'"/>';
    }

   $gallery = new Gallery;
   $gallery->image = $filename;
   $gallery->save();
}
```

view:

```
<form action="uploaded" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-group" name="file[]" multiple>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please edit the answer: the code is a bit messed up and is not clear what is the problem. What error have you got?

Answer (score 0):

Although i don´t really know what your problem is, I think you should change `Input` to `$request`.

Like this:

```
public function upload(Request $request){

    $image = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

    $filename = time().$image;
    if($request->hasFile('file')){

       echo 'uploaded <br/>';
       $file = request->file('file');
       $file->move('upload', $filename);
       echo '<img src="upload/' . $filename .'"/>';
    }

   $gallery = new Gallery;
   $gallery->image = $filename;
   $gallery->save();
}
```